# Snap-Heist: why my template is not rendered?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework, heist

I'm trying to render a template using Snap and Heist.

I'm sure my handler function is called correctly (if I replace handler function's content with `undefined`, it fails as expected. `Debug.Trace.trace` also works as expected).

This handler function consists of one line: `render "template"`. But for some reason I'm getting `No handler accepted <url>` error instead of a `template not found` or something like that.

I think the problem here is that I'm placing my template in wrong directory, but there's no way to know where are searched for templates. So my question is:

1. Isn't this error message misleading? It should have been something like `template not found: template.tpl`
2. Where can I know which directories are searched for templates?

I think the snap application created by `snap init` is the problem. I only made slight modifications on it:

- I added one more field to `App` record: `_myapp :: Snaplet Myapp`
- In `app` initializer function, I added: `n <- embedSnaplet "myapp" myapp myappInit` and then passed n to record.
- I created new file `src/Myapp.hs`.

Here are relevant parts in `Myapp.hs`:

```
myappInit = do
    ...
    h <- nestSnaplet "" heist $ hesitInit "myapp_templates"
    addRoutes routes
    ...

routes = [ ("/submit", submitHandler) ]

submitHandler = trace "rendering submit" $ render "submit"
```

But for some reason even though I see `rendering submit` printed to console when I go to `http://0.0.0.0:8000/myapp/submit`, I get `No handler accepted "/hsnews/submit"` message as HTTP response (instead of rendered template). I have `submit.tpl` and `_submit.tpl` in `snaplets/heist/myapp_templates`.

Answer (score 2):

1.: I agree that there should be two different types of errors for rendering templates. Sadly as far as I know that isn't the case.

2.: **Short answer:** The directory used is written in your heistInit function. e.g.

```
h <- nestSnaplet "" heist $ heistInit "templates"
```

means that all the files in "snaplets/heist/**templates/**" can be accessed, including sub directories.

---

**Long answer:**

The default behaviour of the heist directory stucture works as follows:
All .tpl files are accessible from the snaplet/heist/templates/ directory. Meaning

```
addRoutes [("template", render "template")]
```

will access the file

```
snaplets/heist/templates/template.tpl
```

Which can be accessed at the url

```
http://localhost:8000/template
```

You can also use sub directories, e.g.:

```
addRoutes [("users", render "users/index")]
path = snaplets/heist/templates/users/index.tpl
url  = http://localhost:8000/users
```

To modify this behaviour you can adjust the heistInit function.

Let's say you want the directory path to be "snaplets/heist/" instead of "snaplets/heist/templates/"

simply change:

```
h <- nestSnaplet "" heist $ heistInit "templates"
```

to this:

```
h <- nestSnaplet "" heist $ heistInit ""
```

The argument of heistInit is the directory location of your tpl files.
So you could adjust that however you wish.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I just want to add that because of the way snap works we can't improve the error message in this case.  Snap's routing is very general, so our error messages have to be general.  If you want better error messages, you should structure your routes in a way that allows you to set up better error messages yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Attic's answer is very good, but didn't solve my problem. This is because of a difference between `nestSnaplet` and `embedSnaplet`.

I don't think `embedSnaplet`'s documentation mention this difference:

> Runs another snaplet's initializer and returns the initialized Snaplet value. The difference between this and nestSnaplet is the first type parameter in the third argument. The "v1 v1" makes the child snaplet think that it is top-level, which means that it will not be able to use functionality provided by snaplets included above it in the snaplet tree. This strongly isolates the child snaplet, and allows you to eliminate the b type variable. The embedded snaplet can still get functionality from other snaplets, but only if it nests or embeds the snaplet itself.

but there is also this difference, in `embedSnaplet`, child snaplet has a new root directory in `snaplets/embeddedSnapletName` and all children snaplets of the embedded snaplet will use `snaplets/embeddedSnapletName` folder as root.

So I had to put my `templates` folder to `snaplets/myapp/templates` and that solved it.